# Android, Proguard & XmlPullParser: NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, proguard, xmlpullparser

I am using XmlPullParser and when the app pass throught the `Proguard`, and the apk is running on device, it give me the following error:

```
08-06 17:10:26.717: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser.d
```

I have added `-ignorewarnings` in my proguard.cfg or otherwise there is no way to pass the `Proguard`.

Here is a link to my [proguard.cfg](http://pastebin.com/8mj5WUaR) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obfuscated away a method you shouldn't have. You need to keep the pull parser code intact. Add:

```
-keep public class org.xmlpull.**
```

to your proguard.cfg file.

Comment: Thanks, but now another error: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1..java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Answer (score 0):

what you want in your proguard config file is -keep  instead of -ignorewarnings

```
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```

See the following url for some more details

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html

> **But Wait, My App is Crashing Now**
>
> > Most crashes happen because Proguard has obfuscated away something that your application needs,
> >     such as a class that is referenced in the AndroidManifest or within a
> >     layout, or perhaps something called from JNI or reflection. The
> >     Proguard configuration provided here tries to avoid obfuscating most
> >     of these cases, but it’s still possible that in edge cases you’ll end
> >     up seeing something like a ClassNotFoundException.
>
> You can make edits to the procfg.txt file to keep classes that have
>   been obfuscated away. Adding:
>
> ```
> -keep public class * [my classname]
> ```
>
> should help. For more information about how to prevent Proguard from
>   obfuscating specific things, see the Proguard manual. Specifically,
>   the keep section. In the interest of security, try to keep as little
>   of your application unobfuscated as possible.
>
> The standard settings provided in procfg.txt will be good for many
>   applications, and will catch many common cases, but they are by no
>   means comprehensive. One of the things that we’ve done is had Proguard
>   create a bunch of output files in the obf directory to help you debug
>   these problems.
>
> The mapping.txt file explains how your classes have been obfuscated.
>   You’ll want to make sure to keep this around once you have submitted
>   your build to Market, as you’ll need this to decipher your stack
>   traces.

Comment: Thanks, but now another error: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1..java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: why dont you post your proguard.cfg so we can take a look at what your doing wrong.